# I'd like to create a url link on the current page to an existing form using the current url

Tags: django, url

I'm learning Django by following the mdn locallibrary tutorial and would really like some help constructing links to update and delete authors.

I have created a link to my create author form (`<li><a href="{% url 'author_create' %}">Add Author</a></li>`) which works fine.
What I am trying to do next is to grab the trailing integer from the current page (my author_detail.html) url e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/authors/12`

and then create a new url that links to my update author form. I have added the following code to the end of my author_detail.html file:

```
  {% if user.is_staff %}
  <hr />
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li>Staff</li>
  {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'author_create' %}">Add Author</a></li>
    <li>{{ currentUrl}}...current url</li>
  {% endif %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
```

The 'Add Author' link works fine but I have absolutely no idea how to construct the url 
to update the author on which the current page is displaying.

In the code above, the second list item is trying to display the current page url,
 it doesn't work and I just get '...current url' displayed.

I actually want to construct the url to allow the user to update the
 current author

I have this class defined in my views.py:

```
class AuthorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Author

    def page(request):
        currentUrl = request.get_full_path()
        return render(request, '/page.html', locals())
```

My author form template is:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and my url mappings in urls.py are:

```
urlpatterns += [  
    path('author/create/', views.AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author_create'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/update/', views.AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='author_update'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/delete/', views.AuthorDelete.as_view(), name='author_delete'),
]
```

It appears to be a relatively simple task to achieve, but I have been
 failing for a few days now in trying to construct the url links to the
update and delete forms of the app.

The only way a user can get to these forms currently is by typing the
correct url into the browser address bar. e.g.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/author/12/update/`

or:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/author/12/delete/`

I hope this explains what I am trying to achieve, I've found it difficult!
And impossible in finding a solution

Comment: so you want to generate the url for update and delete page while you are on the visiting the page for an author?

Comment: Thank you Nalin, that's exactly what I was trying to do. @Daniel posted the solution below which works perfectly for me.

Comment: PS: Thank you Nalin for editing my original post, it reads much better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't think in terms of the current URL, but rather in terms of the context of the page.

This is an author detail view, so you already have an item named `author` - also referenced as `object` - in the template, and you are presumably already using it to display data from the author model, such as `{{ author.name }}` etc. So you can use that to create your link:

```
{% url "author_update" pk=author.pk %}
```

(Note, I don't know why you have defined a `page` method in your AuthorDetailView class. That method will never be called by anything; you should delete it.)

Comment: A far better solution to what my brain  was trying to do, which was:  grab the current url, stringify it, chop the integer off the end and then construct the new url including the obtained  iteger i.e. the author record primary key. I will now delete the `page` method from my Author DetailView class! Thank you again. I have much still to learn.